# Conditional layout Azure AD B2C login page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I am analyzing Azure AD b2c as a solution as identity access management platform and one thing I need to achieve is custom page layout for login page per application.

I saw that you can vary the layout per culture in Microsoft documentation but could I pass a custom query string or URL path or even just vary based on the client id the layout I want to show? There is not documentation about that. My best guess is that I could use custom policies with custom layout to achieve that. However documentation on custom policies is lacking.

One other approach would be to do my own login app that would take care of that custom logic. But I don't know if we can do that with Azure AD b2c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a seperate custom policy for each application if your per-app customisations is significant. Otherwise you can use [dynamic page branding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-dynamic-custom-page-content-uri).